# Bash if statement equal output from last command

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to equal something from last command with bash if statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

monit status

if [ "status" != "error" ]; then
        echo -e "hostname\ttest\t0\t0" | /usr/sbin/send_nsca -H hostname -c /etc/send_nsca.cfg
        exit 1;
fi
```

Even if the `monit status` gives out `status = online with all services` it runs the echo command. I can not figure out how to make the `if` statement match the status of `monit status` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the static strings `status` vs. `error`.

There are several ways to go about this. For capturing the output of the command in a variable, use

```
STATUS=`monit status`
```

or

```
STATUS=$(monit status)
```

For a simple case as your's, I would go for a simple

```
if monit status | grep -q error ; then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Backticks are deprecated in favor of `$()`.